# datagrid has "!" symbol even after validation errors were fixed

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, and one of it's columns has a validator specified. If I input an incorrect value, then the cell is displayed in red border (as expected), and a "!" symbol is displayed at the left in the row. After I input a correct value, the red border disappears, but the "!" symbol remains. Why does it remain? How to get rid of it?

Also I've noticed that the underlying value does get updated even if the data is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If I specify:

```
    <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate />
    </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```

then I don't see any "!" symbol when the error is cleared, but I also don't see it if error is present. It is still better than previous behaviour, but I would like to see this symbol if there is an error and not see it if there are no errors. So your answers are still welcome :) .

Comment: This should be in your question, not as an answer.  Are you raising PropertyChanged event when you change your properties?